# Finding all contiguous subarrays

Tags: python, algorithm, sub-array

Here i have a elementList which holds the data with only 0's and 1's .I throw the data to temporaryList from elementList to examine all of the subarrays .
I am trying to find the total number of contiguous subarrays that contains only one '1' .

I checked the subarrays whether they are correct or not by printing them . They are fine but my subarrayCounter does not gives the correct value and i can not see my problem ( i am sure that there is a stupid mistake , sorry)  .

any idea would be ok. thanks

```
for i in range (0,len(elementlist)):
    maxwidth = len(elementlist)  - i 
    for j in range (0 , maxwidth):
        tempList.append(elementlist[i+j])
   
        for m in range (0 , len(tempList)) : 
            if tempList[m] == '1' : 
                counter += 1

        if counter == int(numberOne) : 
            subarrayCounter += 1
        counter = 0
    
        
            
    tempList.clear()
```

for example when i have 0 1 1 0 1 in my list if i try when i try to print the print the contiguous subarrays it gives the correct answer :

```
    for i in range (0,len(elementlist)):
        maxwidth = len(elementlist)  - i 
        for j in range (0 , maxwidth):
            tempList.append(elementlist[i+j])
            print(tempList) # added print here
            for m in range (0 , len(tempList)) : 
                if tempList[m] == '1' : 
                    counter += 1

            if counter == int(numberOne) : 
                subarrayCounter += 1
            counter = 0
    
        
            
        tempList.clear()
```

OUTPUT :

```
    ['0']
    ['0', '1']
    ['0', '1', '1']
    ['0', '1', '1', '0']
    ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1']
    ['1']
    ['1', '1']
    ['1', '1', '0']
    ['1', '1', '0', '1']
    ['1']
    ['1', '0']
    ['1', '0', '1']
    ['0']
    ['0', '1']
    ['1']
```

Comment: Just as a side note, I think you can use sliding window approach here.

Comment: Can't you just check if counter>=1 then increment subarrayCounter ?

Comment: Have a look at [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby). You can convert sub-arrays into single items, filter out the 0 values, and count the results.

Comment: Do you need to find *only* the number of subarrays?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg no , the number of the contiguous subarrays which contains only one '1' .

Comment: @rootkonda there's no problem in there . int(numberOne)  == 1 . It was implemented on the previous lines of my code so you could not see that .

Comment: @Ozan - I dont understand. If you compare counter==1 and counter seems to keep the count of continuous 1's. How will it work ?

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357930/given-a-binary-string-10110-find-the-count-of-all-the-substring-with-number-o/63358092#63358092). Your problem is simplified version with k=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code is a simple way to solve this question.

```
def countSubArraysWithSingle1(elementlist):
  subarrayCounter = 0
  for i in range (0,len(elementlist)):
    for j in range (i , len(elementlist)):
      if elementlist[i:j+1].count('1') == 1:
        print(elementlist[i:j+1])
        subarrayCounter += 1
  print("Total count: ",subarrayCounter)
```

**I/P:** ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1']
**O/P:**

```
['0', '1']
['1']
['1']
['1', '0']
['0', '1']
['1']
Total count: 6
```

**Explanation:**
The code finds out all the sub-arrays in the following order and runs a count function on each sub-array which counts the number of '1's in it and returns the count. We check if the count returned is 1 or not, if it is then we increment the subarrayCounter by 1:

```
['0'].count('0') => 0
**['0', '1'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
['0', '1', '1'].count('1') => 2
['0', '1', '1', '0'].count('1') => 2
['0', '1', '1', '0', '1'].count('1') = 3
**['1'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
['1', '1'].count('1') => 2
['1', '1', '0'].count('1') => 2
['1', '1', '0', '1'].count('1') => 3
**['1'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
**['1', '0'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
['1', '0', '1'].count('1') => 2
['0'].count('1') => 0
**['0', '1'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
**['1'].count('1') => 1 {increment subarrayCounter by 1}**
```

*Hope it helps!*